# Css alignent in Chat boxes

Tags: css

[image]

I am having issues in aligning the chat boxes in my app.The senders and the receiver's chat box is overlapping.

#### Here's the css classes used on each block

```
        .white_block
        {
           background-color: #d5dfed; 
           border-radius: 10px; 
           padding: 10px 0 10px 10px; 
           width: 60%; 
           margin-top: 10px;
        }
        .blue_block
        {
            background-color: rgba(0, 150, 255, 1); 
            border-radius: 10px;
            padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;
            width: 60%;
            margin-top: 10px;
            float: right;
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your goal?

Comment: Please show the HTML code too

Comment: Without looking at your code we won't be able to provide a solution which would suit you

Answer (score 1):

Assign separate < div > for both white and blue block

#### Below is the code to prove the same.

```css
* {
  font-family: "arial";
  
}

.white_block {
  background-color: #d5dfed;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;
  width: 60%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.blue_block {
  background-color: rgba(0, 150, 255, 1);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;
  width: 60%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="white_block">
  <p>The price quoted for the campus is too high please reconsider the price</p>
</div>
<div class="white_block">
  <p>L</p>
</div>
<div class="blue_block">
  <p>This is the best price we can offer</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

increase the value margin try using margin-bottom margin give space outer side of block